# SSAS Handling snapshot cumulative measures

Tags: ssas, mdx, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I have project to build a Cube using Microsoft BI Stack to handle Project Progress reports.
I have issue on how to handle semi additive or cumulative measures.

I now receive monthly or weekly reports that show something like :

- Project Original Value
- Value Added This Report
- Current Project Value (which is Original + Total Value Added Till Now)
  For each Project currently present in the Company.

I believe i should design a snapshot type warehouse each row is the report for that project that just arrived.

I am not sure however how to handle the measures of Current Project Value, where its possible for user to know what is Total Value of Projects for a year , which would be the Sum of the Last Reported Value for the projects that came during that year . Or view this measure by Country or Department.

Comment: Could you please add `some example numbers` for a particular snapshot and expected value for the entire year? To be sure, that business idea is understood correctly. And please also mention, how you design snapshot SSAS DB. Do you use `SCOPE by Date` to split snapshots from a solid data table/view?

Comment: `SO` is a code Q-A site - this question is not about code. I will vote to close and move to the data base specific site. @AlexPeshik - what do you think... interesting question but wrong site?

Comment: Hm... I thought that author got the idea if building DWH, and he's asking about managing snapshots in SSAS DB. Something like: if snapshots are by SCOPEs, so cumilative measures should be created by writing another SCOPEs, which override date snapshots. And it's kind of code part. But I might understand the question wrong.